# Record audio using MediaStore Api

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I'm trying to record the audio using the mediaStore API, but I don't know how it works.

This is the code without the API.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");
try {
    file.createNewFile();

    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

    int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
            2,
            2);

    short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

    AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(1,
            11025,
            2,
            2,
            minBufferSize);

    audioRecord.startRecording();

    while(recording){
        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
            dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
        }
    }

    if(!recording){
        audioRecord.stop();
        dataOutputStream.close();
    }


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I do that using it? Also in my I case I want to use `AudioRecord` instead of `MediaRecorder` so I can change to frequency after that.

Comment: You can't. You can use MediaStream api.

Comment: but i'm to trying to make a voice changer so how can i do that

Comment: Voice changer? ..

Comment: You mean that modifies the voice quality, sound etc.?

Comment: change the Frequency

Comment: So for that you have to use MediaRecorder

Comment: the problem is i've to use the MediaStore and audioRecorder. because i already have the code to change the frquency

Comment: You cant do it with mediastore,

Comment: MediaStore is just for accessing files in android

Comment: You can use Soundpool